# how to add text and math to existing pdf by Python

Tags: python, pdf, math, matplotlib

My problem is:

1. for example, I have drawn a graph with a few nodes using some software for example, yEd, open office draw, etc. I have saved the graph in a pdf format.
2. I would like to have labels for the nodes. The labels are math symbols, for example z^n_{t,t+1} in latex format. We assume that those software can not produce pretty math equations.
3. Now what I think might be possible is:

   a. import the pdf file

   b. Python can print pretty math equations. If I could add math equations at arbitrary locations, that will be great.

   c. save the modified pdf file

What is the best method to do this by Python? or is there any such methods? Some posts suggest "from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas", but I can not write proper math equations by canvas.

Comment: What is your exact use case here? There might be a much easier way to get when you need done here depending on what it is you need to achieve?

Comment: @shuttle87, I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: If all your previous work is in LaTeX format then you might do better to generate the pdf documents from LaTeX itself. If you have access to the data from which the graphs are made you might want to draw those directly and not using something like open office. You can automate a lot of this process using python. Currently I'm writing a tutorial about this, it's a bit of a broad topic though.

Comment: For PostScript the [psfrag package](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) is very useful for replacing labels. For PDF, [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/16923) [questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64478/16923) on TeX SE discuss some alternatives. You may also consider `pdf2ps` or `pdftops` to turn the PDF into PS on which psfrag can operate. Unless you use PDF-specific features like transparency.